# Git questions - not in a branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

Firstly, how can I see which branch I am currently on? I typed "git branch" but it returned

```
* (no branch)
  master
```

so then when I commit, where are these changes being committed to?

Secondly, how can I get the changes I have made onto the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you commit something in that situation, the commit is created the same way as normally, but there is no branch pointing to it. To make it easier to find the commit afterwards (i.e. without remembering the hash or using reflog) and to protect against the garbage collector, you can create a branch to it even after committing:

```
git commit
git branch tmp
```

After that one way of getting the changes back to master is the following, assuming that the checked out commit was a parent of master:

```
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

Comment: it says I have unstaged changes and cannot commit when I try the "git rebase master"

Comment: You need to commit all files before rebasing (or use git stash, which actually is also one kind of a commit).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick to get it into your local master and push it to the remote origin

```
  git stash
  git checkout master
  git stash pop  
  git add .
  git commit -m "my changes.."
  git push origin master
```

Comment: okay that all worked...now do I have to push? what was the command for that?

Comment: but this put it back to the HEAD without my revisions (luckily I saved my revisions prior to doing this)....I simply want to replace the current head with the code I now have.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently in "detached head" mode. So git isn't lying to you: you're not on a branch, or rather not on one with a name.

In spite of that, your current commit still has history. I'm going to assume you've already committed any changes you made, so your working copy is clean: if not, use `git stash` or `git commit` to get those changes out of the way.

To get the commits "out" to master, you have two options. First, you can change what master *is* to be your current branch:

```
git branch -d master
git branch master
git checkout master
```

... that will only succeed if all the changes in "master" are present in your current unnamed branch.

The other way is to check out master and then merge/rebase/cherry-pick in your current changes:

```
git checkout master
git merge HEAD@{1} # HEAD@{1} is "where HEAD was previously"
```

You get into the "detached head" state by doing something like `git checkout HEAD~1`, where you check out something that isn't the HEAD of a branch.